# What is the simplest way to view styled text (e.g. in HTML) in a Java application?

Tags: java, styledtext

I want to view styled text, for example in html (not html file, just html string). I've tried using JEditorPane but it's so difficult, is there any more simple way?

Comment: Old IE allowed to visit about:<html>string here</html> ... not anymore :(

Comment: JEditorPane supports HTML.  What's hard about it?

Comment: @Alnitak how to insert HTML to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JEditorPane.setText(htmlString)
```

[JEditorPane tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: Of course, I've tried this but tags had been viewed. I've solved this using setContentType(). Thanks.